# why profile link redirects to homepage?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to view the profile page of my website and keeps redirecting me to homepage instead of vendors profile

No visible error is been displayed.
can someone help please

here is the link i'm trying to view https://booksafariafrica.com/en/profile/32

this is the code

```html
<div class="owner-info widget-box">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="{{route('user.profile',['id'=>$vendor->id])}}" target="_blank" >
                @if($avatar_url = $vendor->getAvatarUrl())
                    <img class="avatar avatar-96 photo origin round" src="{{$avatar_url}}" alt="{{$vendor->getDisplayName()}}">
                @else
                    <span class="avatar-text">{{ucfirst($vendor->getDisplayName()[0])}}</span>
                @endif
            </a>
        </div>
```

My controller

```html
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: h2 gaming
 * Date: 8/17/2019
 * Time: 3:05 PM
 */
namespace Modules\User\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Modules\FrontendController;

class ProfileController extends FrontendController
{
    public function profile(Request $request,$id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        if(empty($user)){
            abort(404);
        }
        if(!$user->hasPermissionTo('dashboard_vendor_access'))
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $data['page_title'] = $user->getDisplayName();
        $this->registerCss('module/user/css/profile.css');
        return view('User::frontend.profile.profile',$data);
    }
```

My routes

```html
Route::group(['prefix'=>'profile'],function(){
    Route::match(['get'],'/{id}','ProfileController@profile')->name("user.profile");
```

Comment: Please share your routes file

Comment: There is no stable issue that causes this behavior,  its related to the code profile itself in index(){} so check the index and check your routing and  check your model or edit your question and add the things i tild you about to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

```php
if(!$user->hasPermissionTo('dashboard_vendor_access'))
{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Your problem is probably being caused by this code block, as it does a redirect to the homepage if the condition is met.

So make sure the `$user` has the proper permissions assigned to it.

Comment: the  vendor can access the dashboard, the problem is the user who is not authenticated and wants to view the vendor profile. For example at    this page https://booksafariafrica.com/tour/masai-mara-offers at the top has vendor profile url to see the travel packages he has listed, when you click that url it directs to homepage instead of vendor profile page.

Comment: Do unauthenticated users have the proper permissions to view the vendor profile page? If this page can be viewed by unauthenticated users, I don't think its logical to protect. Unless I'm missing something here, the section `$user->hasPermissionTo('dashboard_vendor_access')` is probably returning `false`, but since you have negated it, it becomes `true` and the redirect condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```html
if(!$user->hasPermissionTo('dashboard_vendor_access'))
{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

then have to remove the Exclamation mark and worked just fine.